# PHP Select from multiple tables and add value together to get total

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to run these queries in PHP to a mysql table

```
$sql="SELECT * from customer where customerid > '' and voicemail_max > '' and company_status = '' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($customer=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $sql2="SELECT * from client where parent_client_id = '".$customer["customerid"]."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$pbx01_conn);
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        $sql3="SELECT * from extension where client_id = '".substr($result2["id"],1,3)."' ";
        $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$pbx01_conn);
        while($result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
        {
            $sql4="SELECT * from extension_voicemail where extension_id = '".$result3["id"]."' ";
            $rs4=mysql_query($sql4,$pbx01_conn);
            $voicemail_size_total=0;
            while($result4=mysql_fetch_array($rs4)) {
                $voicemail_size_total = $voicemail_size_total+$result4["filesize"];
            }
        }
    }
    echo $voicemail_size_total;
}
```

it should be adding up multiple values from one column

the `$sql4` query looks like:

```
SELECT * from extension_voicemail where extension_id = '1454'
```

and when  i run that in the database, it returns one row with the file size column as 31780

but when i echo `$voicemail_size_total` variable, it shows nothing.

it works fine if i echo that variable one line up from where it is, but where it is now shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `$voicemail_size_total=0;` outside of all of the while loops. Everytime you get back to the loop you re-set that back to 0. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you want to achieve:
1. If you want to get a total of all the filesizes (basicly you are expecting just one value to be presented ) try this:

```
$sql="SELECT * from customer where customerid > '' and voicemail_max > '' and company_status = '' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$voicemail_size_total=0;
while($customer=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $sql2="SELECT * from client where parent_client_id = '".$customer["customerid"]."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$pbx01_conn);
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        $sql3="SELECT * from extension where client_id = '".substr($result2["id"],1,3)."' ";
        $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$pbx01_conn);
        while($result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
        {
            $sql4="SELECT * from extension_voicemail where extension_id = '".$result3["id"]."' ";
            $rs4=mysql_query($sql4,$pbx01_conn);
            while($result4=mysql_fetch_array($rs4)) {
                $voicemail_size_total = $voicemail_size_total+$result4["filesize"];
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $voicemail_size_total;
```

2. If you're looking for the filesizes of each client (ie. expecting a series of filesizes to be presented ) try this:

```
$sql="SELECT * from customer where customerid > '' and voicemail_max > '' and company_status = '' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($customer=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $sql2="SELECT * from client where parent_client_id = '".$customer["customerid"]."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$pbx01_conn);
    $voicemail_size_total=0;
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        $sql3="SELECT * from extension where client_id = '".substr($result2["id"],1,3)."' ";
        $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$pbx01_conn);
        while($result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
        {
            $sql4="SELECT * from extension_voicemail where extension_id = '".$result3["id"]."' ";
            $rs4=mysql_query($sql4,$pbx01_conn);
            while($result4=mysql_fetch_array($rs4)) {
                $voicemail_size_total = $voicemail_size_total+$result4["filesize"];
            }
        }
    }
    echo $voicemail_size_total;
}
```